# Do smart Contracts need Ether?

Tags: solidity

I have been learning solidity for a few weeks already, deploying contracts on test blockchain to test functions etc ... but today i had an issue and wondered if Smart contract needs ether for some fuctions to work ?

i tried searching on the web but found nothing.

so here my question if i were to sell tokens i bought from the smart contract does it need ether
to be able to buy the tokens back?

And do i need to send ether to my contract?

Answer (score 0):

When you ask if a smart contract needs ether, I'm going to narrow my answer down to "needs ether for gas" because obviously a smart contract needs ether if you explicitly code it to need ether.

As far as gas goes... smart contracts do not pay gas. A smart contract is simply code that is stored on the blockchain waiting to be called by an external account (or other smart contract as an intermediary.) The account that makes the call will pay the gas fees.

There is no such thing as a native CRON job or a smart contract making itself execute to buy back tokens. In order for a contract to "be able to buy the tokens back" an external account (think, a user) would need to call the necessary function to buy the tokens back and pay the gas.

Without knowing how the smart contract is coded, the smart contract may need ether or other tokens to actually buy back the tokens, but these are not going to be used to pay the gas fees for the transaction.